# How to get the list of visible workspaces in XMonad?

Tags: xmonad

How do you get a list of visible workspaces (workspaces that are currently displayed on the monitors) in xmonad? Currently in my xmonad.hs config file the command (XMonad.workspaces conf) gives me the list of all workspaces. I'm not very familiar with Haskell and so I'm having trouble understanding the documentation like this: http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-StackSet.html

Comment: I got an answer to this question via this thread here: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2012-August/012879.html

Answer (score 0):

```
visibleWorkspaces :: X [WorkspaceId]
visibleWorkspaces = do
  ws <- gets windowset
  return $ map W.tag $ W.current ws : W.visible ws
```